# How to check if string is valid URL to image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, uri, ruby-2.0, url-validation

I have the following class:

```
require 'uri'

class Images

  IMAGE_NOT_FOUND = '/images/no_image.gif'

  attr_accessor :url

  def initialize(parameters = {})
    @url = parameters.fetch(:url, IMAGE_NOT_FOUND)
    @url = IMAGE_NOT_FOUND unless @url =~/^#{URI::regexp}$/
  end

end
```

holding `URL` to image. I have checked some questions and add `URL` validation, but I need to improve it validating `URLs` pointing to images only.If validation fails, I want to use default image showing there is some issue.

Note, the current validation of the `URL` is not working with relative paths. For example, the following `url` is valid as image source `/images/image1.png` but the current validation is not recognizing it.

Could anyone tell if this is possible using `URI`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to only validate the `URLs` pointing to image type of files.

For eg: `http://www.xyz.com/logo.png` or `http://www.xyz.com/logo.gif` or `http://www.xyz.com/logo.jpg`

Here's the solution:

```
require 'uri'

class Images

  IMAGE_NOT_FOUND = '/images/no_image.gif'

  attr_accessor :url

  def initialize(parameters = {})
    @url = parameters.fetch(:url, IMAGE_NOT_FOUND)
    @url = IMAGE_NOT_FOUND unless ((File.extname(@url) =~/^(.png|.gif|.jpg)$/ )||(@url =~ /^#{URI::regexp}$/))
  end

end
```

The above example will only allow url's pointing to images with extension `.png or .gif or .jpg` and rest would be set to `IMAGE_NOT_FOUND`. Add more extensions if you want to.

Comment: Just a bit tweak. You could write `if (File.extname(@url) =~/^(.png|.gif|.jpg)$/).nil?` as `unless File.extname(@url) =~/^(.png|.gif|.jpg)$/`

Comment: @KirtiThorat +1, but this is validating the image extension but it requires full url path - in most cases the path to images is relative. For exmaple: `/images/myimate.jpg`. Also I believe you should use `&&` instead of `||`